# How can I apply a color lookup table in R plotly

Tags: r, colors, plotly

For data involving sports teams, I want to apply consistent custom colors from a lookup table for any charts I produce. This is my current effort

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

lookup <- tibble(team=c("Dolphins","Sharks","Minnows"), color_id =c("dodgerblue","red","black"))

data <- tibble(team =c("Dolphins","Sharks","Minnows","Sharks"),V1=c(1:4),V2=c(4:1))

df <- data %>% 
    left_join(lookup)


colors <- lookup$color_id

plot_ly(df, x= ~ V1, y= ~ V2, color = ~ color_id, name =  ~ team, colors = colors)
```

[image: Output]

As you can see, the legend does not identify the colors appropriately. e.g Dolphins should be dodgerblue

Thanks in advance

Comment: This almost works:  `plot_ly(df, x= ~ V1, y= ~ V2, color = ~team, name =  ~ team, colors = ~color_id )`.  Not a very satisfying, but this work: `plot_ly(df, x= ~ V1, y= ~ V2, color = I(df$color_id), name = ~ team)`

Comment: @Dave2e. Thanks for that. I had it in my head that I() could only be used with constants e.g. I(:"red"). Glad to avoid factors! Do you want to redo as a formal answer so I can credit you?

Answer (score 1):

You have the colors defined in your initial dataframe so there are two potential options that seems close to the desired solution.
The I( ) is used to specify the variable is the identity (ie Use this value as is and do not interpret as a factor)

```
library(plotly)

df <- structure(list(team = c("Dolphins", "Sharks", "Minnows", "Sharks"
), V1 = 1:4, V2 = 4:1, color_id = c("dodgerblue", "red", "black", 
"red")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

colors <- lookup$color_id
#original
plot_ly(df, x= ~ V1, y= ~ V2, color = ~ color_id, name =  ~ team, colors = colors)  #wrong order, 1 different color
```

Here you want to color by the variable team using "colors" to specify the palette.

```
#this works but color palette needs to the same order as the teams 
plot_ly(df, x= ~ V1, y= ~ V2, color = ~team, name =  ~ team, size=I(70), 
         colors = c("dodgerblue", "black", "red") )
```

Since you all ready have a vector of the desired palette in your data frame a second option to specify the color option directly.

```
#If we manually specify the desired colors by directly referencing the data frame it works:
plot_ly(df, x= ~ V1, y= ~ V2, color = ~I(color_id), name =  ~ team, size=I(50))
```

[image]